# vsscanf read length

Tags: c, scanf

What i need is:

1) read from string as sscanf does
2) measure the length of processed sequence as sscanf does with "%n"
3) accept `format` and other arguments from above (no control over it)

is there a way how to do it?

```
size_t read = 0; //Accumulator of the length of processed characters

void readfn (char* source_string, char* fmt, va_list args)
{
  int length;

  size_t fmtlen = strlen(fmt);

  char* fmt_and_lenght = (char*)realloc(fmt, fmtlen + 3);

  fmt_and_length[fmtlen]     = '%';
  fmt_and_length[fmtlen + 1] = 'n';
  fmt_and_length[fmtlen + 2] = '\0';

  va_list args_and_length = va_append(args, length); //here is the problem, i need to add &length to the list (i dont care if the list is created from scretch

  vsscanf(source_str, fmt_and_length, args_and_length); //here i finally capture the length of processed string

  read += length; //and i do whatever i wanted to do with it
}
```

which would simply count the number of consumed characters even if the fmt didnt contain "%n" and the argument list did not capture it before?

**EDIT**: it would definitely be better if there was vsnscanf or what name should it have, which would get the number of processed chars. But i solved this by splitting the format string by unescaped %. If it is not followed by * i fetch one argument and iteratively i handle all of them, each time i add "%n" and at the end i sum up the lengths.

Comment: No idea what you're asking here, could you rephrase more clearly?

Comment: i edited the question, so its clearer i hope

Answer (score 0):

There's no portable way to do this.  I'd suggest you refactor your code so that you don't need to do this at all.  You might be able to cobble something together with the [ffcall library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/), but it'll be messy and fragile.

Comment: I thought it would not be possible to do this portably, but it also cannot be done much better by refactoring the code, this is just a functionality that i need, so i will reimplement scanf it seems